# Django user authentication with phone and Email

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to customize my Django user authentication system so users can sign up/in with both phone number and email (OTP and password).
What should I do?

How can I customize my user model? Should I use AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser or something else?

Comment: https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/